# Android smsManager.sendTextMessage throwing exception 'Own package not found: package=com.android.phone'

Tags: android, kotlin, android-11, smsmanager

I am using SmsManager to send text message from user's device, but some users are not able to send message from my app. Looks like most of the affected users on Android 11. Does this mean user has deleted the default phone app from their device or will adding below in Manifest file

```
<queries>
    <package android:name="com.android.phone"/>
</queries>
```

will resolve this issue?

Comment: Were you able to solve this? If yes, can you please tell me how?

Comment: @RishavNaskar nah!